# Pass port traffic from home router > pfsense VM > gaming server

Tags: networking, router, pfsense, dmz

I want to setup a gaming server on a physical host I have at home. I am having trouble passing traffic through my home router to the pfsense VM, to the gaming host.

My network looks like this:

```
Home Router > pfsense VM    > gaming server
-------------------------------------------
192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.177 
              192.168.30.2  > 192.168.30.3
```

My pfsense VM is using a bridged network adapter (192.168.1.177) so my home router sees it like it is a physical host. Also, on my home router, I have configured 192.168.1.177 as a DMZ address. The pfsense VM also has another internal adapter with 192.168.30.2 assigned as a static IP.

My gaming server has internet connectivity, but the ports do not appear to be open on the server.

I think I have to setup a NAT but I am unsure of how to pass ports 2302-2306 from my PFsense router (192.168.1.177) to my gaming server (192.168.30.3)

Can anyone help me do this or give me suggestions on where to start?